# Control-F5 Browser Refresh (Flash object not refreshing)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, browser, caching, refresh

Under the hood, I was wondering what Control-F5 for a browser does.

To me, it clears the cache and refreshes images/text/controls/etc. I get that.

**Question:**

What about Flash objects? I've been trying to refresh a page with a Flash control and it doesn't seem to refresh to the latest. It would only refresh after I manually clear the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright so after some investigation it appears that clearing the cache with Control-F5 in IE7 does not delete/clear the xml file that the flash object reads from.

It appears to check if the file exists and if so, it will use that file instead regardless if there's a newer version.

One way to get around this was to make the browser treat each request as if it is requesting a new file and so I had to generate a random number and append it as:

In ActionScript:

```
var xmlPath = "/settings.xml?rand=" + getTimer();
```

Also, if there are flash component changes, you can also do the same by appending a random number to the flash SWF file that is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onkeydown=" 
document.onkeydown = function(e)

{

    if(e) document.onkeypress = function(){return true;}

    var evt = e?e:event;
    if(evt.keyCode==116) 
    {
         //your code

    }
} ">
```

you must put the code in the body event, when you press any key, this function handle every key, in the case of F5 the code is 116

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you're using Firefox try control-shift-R ;)

Comment: Well sorry had to guess since you were incapable of telling us what browser you are using...