# IE refresh breaking Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer

I have isolated an issue I am having with Flash in IE7+ but don't know how to fix it. The issue is when you first go to the flash website in IE everything works fine, but when you refresh nothing appears. I am dynamically loadng in XML and have added the caching fix found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730487/control-f5-browser-refresh-flash-object-not-refreshing) so I have eliminated that bug. What I have discovered is that on refresh IE doesn't load the exported for actionscript movieclips from the library.

Does anyone know why on refresh IE doesn't load the exported for actionscript movieclips from the library?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IE needs to die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a IE problem. FlashPlayer tend to have this problem from time to time. When you put some complicated asset on the first frame in a clip, it fails to intialize sometimes. Probably you can try to refer to the shared library items a bit later, or delay the loading of external library, or append a random parameter for the swf to force the FlashPlayer to reload it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the clips that are linked in your library out on your stage? You can uncheck export at first frame and then put those clips outside the bounds on your stage, say on frame 2, then preload on frame 1. Let me know if that doesn't help.